# UIslider scroll and tableview scroll ios

Tags: ios, scroll, tableview, uislider

This is my scenario I have a UIslider and a Tableview I need to scroll                 tableview with slider value

Comment: Is the cell height fixed for all cells?

Comment: no  it depends on the input label, each cell has its own height :-(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Define UISlider in .h file as

```
UISlider *slider;
```

Here add this in viewdidload

```
slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[slider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
slider.maximumValue =5;
slider.continuous = YES;
slider.value = 25.0;
CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
slider.transform = trans;
[slider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[slider setThumbImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"XYZ.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
[temp addSubview: slider];
```

Define the method  slideraction

```
-(void)sliderAction:(id)sender{NSIndexPath* indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[(UISlider *)sender value] inSection:0];
[yourtableview selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath1 animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
}
```

In cellforrowatindexpath put this at the end

```
UIView *selb = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [selb setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:236/255.0 blue:179/255.0 alpha:1]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selb;
```

in numberofrowsinsection array is number of rows

```
slider.maximumValue = [array count];
```

And thats it you are good to go so the end result will be like u move the slider the table view moves with a cell selected in given color

Answer (score 2):

I think using the function from UIScrollView class can achieve this.

Give this code in the @IBAction method of the slider:

```
@IBAction func setOffset(sender: AnyObject) {
    let slider = sender as! UISlider
    let y = tableView.contentSize.height * CGFloat(slider.value)
    tableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(origin: CGPointMake(0,y), size: tableView.frame.size), animated: true)
 }
```

Note that the slider range should be 0-1

Comment: Change `size: tableView.frame.size`  to a smaller value like  `CGSize(width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 50)`  for better results.

Comment: So, what u are saying is "Set tableViewscroll height to slider value and depending on the sliderValue change the scroll ?" Did I get what u r saying?

Comment: TableView Scroll height is decided by the number of cells and their heights(its fixed after the data is loaded in the cells). `scrollRectToVisible(frame)` scrolls the table view to show the`frame`, (whose y position is decided by the silder value).